# how to extend height of semantic row to bottom of page

Tags: javascript, css, semantic-ui, grid-layout

Im trying to create a grid using semantic-ui. Does anyone know how i can extend a row's height to reach the bottom of the page, and also to extend to a custom size for future reference? Here is what i have:

```
<div className = "ui container" >
    <div className = "stretched ui grid">

        <div className = "ten wide column float left  ">
            <div className = "">
                <FileUpload files = {this.state.files} fileChanged = {this.state.fileChanged} />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div className = " five wide column uploader float right" >
            <div className= "">
                <input type="file" id = "my-file"/> 
            </div>
        </div>  

    </div>

    <div className = "ui segment one column row" style={{height:'50%'}}>
        <CommentSection onCommentButtonClick = {this.handleCommentButtonClick}/>    
    </div>

</div>
```

the bit i want to change is the div with the className `className = "ui segment one column row" style={{height:'50%'}}`. Setting the height to 50% hasnt seemed to do anything at all

Answer (score 1):

You can use FlexBox.

```
<div className = "ui container" style={{flex: 1}} >
    <div className = "stretched ui grid" style={{flex: 1}}>

        <div className = "ten wide column float left  ">
            <div className = "">
                <FileUpload files = {this.state.files} fileChanged = {this.state.fileChanged} />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div className = " five wide column uploader float right" >
            <div className= "">
                <input type="file" id = "my-file"/> 
            </div>
        </div>  

    </div>

    <div className = "ui segment one column row" style={{flex: 1}}}>
        <CommentSection onCommentButtonClick = {this.handleCommentButtonClick}/>    
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is specifying height in %, Semantic UI expects syntax in following format:

```
<div style={{height: spacing  'em'}}
```

So, try:

```
<div className = "ui segment one column row" style={{height: 50}}>
```

Note: semantic ui customized styles in 'em' so by default height property is 50 em in this example.